# Safari - save window / session (like TabCloud for Chrome)

Tags: safari, session

Is there an add-on for Safari (v8.0.5, on Yosemite) that allows the saving of a window? e.g. when doing research on Floorboard DIY, I'd like to save all Tabs that I've viewed.

Note that I don't want to save the Last Session, but instead:

- save one or more Safai as whatever name I want, so it could be restored later

I use [TabCloud](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabcloud/npecfdijgoblfcgagoijgmgejmcpnhof) extension on Chrome to do this.  Would love to find an equivalent on Safari!

I've tried following extensions:

- Sessions - saves all open window as a single session.  Could only
  load that one session
- Surfon - either buggy or I don't know how to use it properly. Can't save different sessions, or I must move them from the temporary
  folder it creates or something.. aahh
- Tab Across - only saves a single session

Any suggestions welcome.  Thanks!

Comment: Get all the tabs into one window, right click one tab - Add bookmarks for these n Tabs. Adds to Favourites bar.

Answer (score 2):

You may find ["Sessions"](https://sessions-extension.github.io/Sessions/) extension for Safari to fit your needs. I have used this extension for a while and I was at one point in your position. This extension went over and beyond my needs for session management.

Make sure to check out the "favorites" features by starring your saved sessions. That way you won't accidentally remove your saved sessions. At times I've sent support request to the active developer and received prompt support. Best of all, this plugin remains to be free and works in the latest Safari (9.1.1 Safari Technology Preview)

Comment: Yeah. The "Sessions" was one of the "must have" extensions. Unfortunately, Apple under the new management destroying everything where some fun is detected. So, started with safari 12, free third party extensions will not work anymore.